# Unexpected end of JSON input when trying to display main page on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

im trying to render the main page in my index page of my node.js server where i store .json files inside my data folder, however when i try running my server it displays "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" at product.js, and following up the error here's wheres its accusing the error

> cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));

here's my whole class on how i model my product

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

    const p = path.join(
      path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename),
      'data',
      'products.json'
    );

    const getProductsFromFile = cb => {
      fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
        if (err) {
          cb([]);
        } else {
          cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));
        }
      });
    };

    module.exports = class Product {
      constructor(title, imageUrl, description, price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
      }

      save() {
        getProductsFromFile(products => {
          products.push(this);
          fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(products), err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
        });
      }

      static fetchAll(cb) {
        getProductsFromFile(cb);
      }
    };
```

Now thats the problem, its accusing a parse error but currently im not storing anything inside a file, therefore i have no idea why is it giving me this error

Comment: Empty string cannot be parsed as a valid JSON..

Comment: oh yeah, that was the case, i purposely inserted some dummy content inside my .json file just for a test, and it worked, thanks!